# Kali Linux The following signatures were invalid

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnupg, apt

when I run this command on Kali Linux

```
sudo apt update
```

I get following error

Err:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates InRelease
The following signatures were invalid: 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5

Again,

```
gpg --fingerprint 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5
```

- pub   dsa1024 2004-09-12 [SC]
- 6302 39CC 130E 1A7F D81A  27B1 4097 6EAF 437D 05B5
- uid  [ unknown] Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key ftpmaster@ubuntu.com
- sub  elg2048 2004-09-12 [E]

Then,

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5
```

- gpg: key 40976EAF437D05B5: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key ftpmaster@ubuntu.com" not changed
- gpg: Total number processed: 1
- gpg:              unchanged: 1

Then,

```
 gpg --export --armor 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
OK

Same result when i run apt update

Comment: Kali isn't Ubuntu or Ubuntu based so, for starters, you shouldn't add Ubuntu repositories let alone now archioved ones (Precise = 12.04, out of support since 2017)

Comment: That is why, when the standard cleanup I posted (now gone) I suggested backing up and re-installing Kali.

Comment: Compulsory link - [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use Ubuntu repositories on Kali Linux, it will break `apt`.

[Non-Kali Repositories](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/)

```
Likewise, adding other operating system’s repositories into Kali (such
as trying to put Ubuntu on Kali), will break your installation. This 
is the single most common reason why Kali Linux systems break.
```

To solve this problem keep only Kali repository:

```
echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib" | sudo tee  /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
sudo apt update
```

Answer (score 0):

As other users have stated in the comments, Kali Linux isn't meant for beginners. We can deduce that you are a beginner from the fact that you think that it is Ubuntu-based (it's not. It's based on Debian `Testing`). I don't know why you would embark on such an endeavor but I suspect it's because of some 3p1k h4xx0r meme. You should try to get your toes wet by using more beginner-friendly distributions.

I am by no means an expert myself: I've been using Linux for around a year or so and I have distrohopped *many, many* distributions before I found one that I settled for. This year has been a fantastic year in regards to learning how Linux works and I have had to find out the hard way, by breaking most of my installs due to tinkering and curiosity. If you have the patience, willingness, and curiosity, I think that you will enjoy the journey, if you can endure the headaches.

Just my two cents.